# Excel X axis label

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel, I want the value of the data marker displayed at the right edge of the data marker.  Ex: an amount representing 0-10 is graphed, and the 10 on the X axis is on the right edge of the column marker.

Answer (score 1):

It can be very difficult to envisage what is required where charts are described rather than illustrated, but as a start would something like this suit (or if not, what's wrong?!)?:

[image]

This uses Between tick marks for Position Axis in Axis Options for the x-axis with Home, Alignment, right justify.